# TSQL RAISERROR as warning

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, throw, raiserror

I'm looking through questions for Microsoft's 70-761 exam and I came across a troublesome one. The question asks to 'produce a **warning** if '.

It seems obvious that I should use `RAISERROR` (or `THROW`) statement. My question is - what severity should I use to fulfill this requirement?

I'm aware that 16 is default for `THROW`, but I hesitate to call it a warning. Maybe `RAISERROR` with severity set to 10 would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should've simply checked the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities

Basically what your answer should be is `RAISERROR` with severity 0-10 (or rather, 0-9).

With `THROW` you can't handle severities because the default one is 16. Therefore, it can't be used to throw a warning.

Comment: I read this article before asking this question. My concern was more about the term 'warning' itself. I'm still not sure if I should use 10 or <10 (wether I should store a message in system log or not). My guess would be not to, but I'd like to avoid guessing when it comes to certification exam.

Comment: I passed this exam myself 2 weeks ago. If you encounter a question like this, you would be given different answers to choose a correct one. It would probably be `RAISERROR` with the severity 0-10 and without adding the message itself to system messages. However if there isn't such an answer but there is one with adding the error to the system messages first, that'd also be correct if the syntax is right. Generally, can't go wrong with 0-10 severity, all of them are warnings as in printouts in the _Messages_ tab of your SSMS _Results_ window and do not break a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL you are looking for:

```
RAISERROR('Warning: <your message>', 0,0) WITH NOWAIT
```

If you need anything "dynamic" in your message, you need something like:

```
DECLARE @messageString varchar(max)     
set @messageString = 'Warning: The time is ' + convert(varchar(max), getdate(), 120) 
RAISERROR(@messageString,0,0) WITH NOWAIT
```

The `WITH NOWAIT` part is important, if you want the message to appear before any surrounding transaction completes.

Comment: Is there any way to collect all the messages in a parent stred procedure?